# What is the equivalent to the LOAD_FILE command in mysql using a rds insance?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I have mysql client installed on an ec2 instance that has access to a Mysql aws rds instance.
I have mysql script that has a  LOAD_FILE('file.txt') statement that I am running from the mysql client, however, that is not going to work because I am using amazon rds MySQL and the data file ('file.txt') is obviously not on the MySQL server host, it is stored on my ec2 instance.

I read you cannot use LOAD_FILE with a mysql rds instance, so what are my options? Is there a way to transfer my file to the database so I can run my LOAD_FILE command to read the file that is now on the server host? I do not want to use the "file.txt" to populate table directly, so I want a way to still be able to use my LOAD_FILE command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command to load a file from your EC2 instance into the RDS database.

You can look here for more info:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html

Or here:
https://medium.com/@abs.abs105/load-data-in-a-csv-file-to-mysql-database-in-an-rds-instance-d9360d84d27b

You may need to tweak the MySQL config to set the local_infile to true.